# How to generate text html in Flutter?

Tags: android, html, flutter, dart

I used flutter_quill: ^6.1.7 to create such a design
But I can't send the html text to the api
Such as `<h1 > Title </h1>`

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [delta_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/delta_markdown) and [markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/markdown) package for this:

```
String quillDeltaToHtml(Delta delta) {
  final markdown = deltaToMarkdown(delta);
  final html = markdownToHtml(markdown);

  return html;
}
```

Comment: This Correct, but I want to send text as ` <h1 > Title </h1>` 

Use _controller.document.toDelta() to extract the deltas output is 
==
` [{insert: This is }, {insert: Test, attributes: {bold: true}}, }]`
Use _controller.document.toPlainText() to extract plain text output is 
= normal text like "This is Test"

Comment: Check now I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

First, install the [`delta_markdown`](https://pub.dev/packages/delta_markdown) and [`markdown`](https://pub.dev/packages/markdown) packages.

Then, try the following code:

```
import 'package:delta_markdown/delta_markdown.dart';
import 'package:markdown/markdown.dart' hide Text;
```

---

```
final QuillController quillController = QuillController.basic();
```

---

```
QuillToolbar.basic(
  controller: quillController,
  …
),
```

---

```
final Delta delta = quillController.document.toDelta();
final String convertedValue = jsonEncode(delta.toJson());
final String markdown = deltaToMarkdown(convertedValue);
final String html = markdownToHtml(markdown);
```